# Run Jenkins job from node in different pools

Tags: jenkins

I would like to create a single Jenkins job that runs a command for Linux and for Windows, where it has a pool of Linux nodes and a pool of Windows nodes to use.

As a simple silly example suppose

1. I want the helloWindows.bat command executed on a single windows node
2. I want the helloLinux.sh command executed on a single Linux node
3. I have a pool of Windows agents under the label Win to choose from
4. I have a pool of Linux agents under the label Lin to choose from

How could I configure this using a Freestyle, Matrix or MultiConfiguration job?

I know how to do logic that will run a Windows batch command on a Windows machine and run a Linux shell command on a Linux machine. However, I don't understand how I can have one windows run be pulled from the Windows pool and one Linux run from the Linux pool.

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with it and I think I figured it out. I'm still testing but so far it looks like it's correct.

1. Multiple Windows agents configured and using label Win
2. Multiple Linux agents configured and using label Lin
3. Create a ***Multi-configureation project***
4. Under Configuration matrix

   1. Add an Axis named Agents
   2. Name it label
   3. Expand the Node/Labels/Labels option
   4. Select Win and Lin
5. Under Build

   1. Use Conditional steps to determine Windows vs. Linux
   2. Use Execute shell for Linux
   3. Use Execute Windows batch command for Windows